# Number of CM lifting of an ordinary elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Before asking my questions I will start with an example: There are two CM elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ with CM field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$, whose $j$-invariants are $-3^3.5^3$ and $3^3. 5^3. 17^3$. Now over $p=2$ (over a suitable ramified extension) they reduce to the same ordinary elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_2$, with $j$-invariant $1$. The reduction is ordinary, so the elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $j=1$ has at least two CM liftings, where the first one is a model of the canonical lifting of Serre-Tate.

My questions: 1) How common does this situation occurs? Does there exist one (or more) non-canonical CM liftings of all (or some) ordinary elliptic curves over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$?

2) Related to my first question; is there a way to classify all CM liftings of a given ordinary elliptic curve?

Throughout my research I all find staff about the canonical lifting, is there a reference about the non-canonical CM liftings?

Comment: I believe these are called quasi-canonical liftings, after a paper of Dick Gross "On canonical and quasi-canonical liftings" (Invent. Math. 84 (1986), 321-326, available from GDZ). Serre-Tate parameters describe liftings in terms of points on the formal multiplicative group, whose origin gives the canonical lifting, and I vaguely remember that torsion points (p-power roots of unity) correspond to quasi-canonical liftings. So they should always exist, though you generally need a ramified base to realize them, as you mention.